# DB user can see no table using ODBC link in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

We are facing an issue with MS access.
There are two users having the same access for tables and previliges in database.
But one user can access the tables from MS access and another user can't.
Can you please let me know the reason.

Thanks for updating from options. I am looking in to it.
User having grant permissions for SELECT ANY TABLE, it works for SQL connection (E.g. Toad or SQL +), but not for MS Access
Is there any issue with MS-Access. Please update me.

Comment: Question asked again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265195/user-facing-an-issue-with-ms-access

Comment: You've revealed in the other instance of this question that your back end is AIX and you're using ODBC to connect to it from Access. This is essential information that you should include in your question -- no one will be able to offer useful help without that information being provided up front.

Answer (score 0):

You say "can see no table", is it possible that code or macro is running that hides the tables and that one user has Tools->Options->Hidden Objects ticked and one does not?

It may be worth typing a query into SQL View of the query design window to see if data is returned:

```
 SELECT * FROM [TableNameHere]
```