# User facing an issue with MS- Access

Tags: ms-access

Currently user using connections to both TEST and PROD instances using MS Access, and everything goes well. By using ABC user. Now user  having problems with APPS user in TEST . 
Also, user having the same problem with user XYZ in PROD instance. This user has the ‘SELECT ANY TABLE’ privilege, so it should be able to see the tables, but doesn’t work from MS Access.
Please suggest us.

Comment: you mean the first user can access the tables in design mode?
I Couldn't understand the issue

Comment: Also asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264939/db-user-can-see-no-table-using-odbc-link-in-ms-access

Comment: Currently user using connections to both TEST and PROD instances using MS Access, and everything goes well. By using ABC user. Now user  having problems with APPS user in TEST . 
Also, user having the same problem with user XYZ in PROD instance. This user has the ‘SELECT ANY TABLE’ privilege, so it should be able to see the tables, but doesn’t work from MS Access.
Please suggest us.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to connect via a SQL connection (I'm assuming ODBC) then you'll be using a predefined set of credentials (i.e. you'll be passing a username and password to Access; probably through the connection string).

Chances are that if your user is unable to get into the database directly, their network (AD?) account is not configured with the same elevated privileges that the ODBC connection has.

Comment: User is providing all the inforamtion. There are 2 users having the same priviliges, one user is able to access the tables from MS -Access with out any issues and another user also able to login but he is not able to see any tables under his user account.

Can you please suggest me..

Comment: Currently user using connections to both TEST and PROD instances using MS Access, and everything goes well. By using ROBLEDIR user. Now user  having problems with APPS user in TEST . He cannot confirm if also there are problems using APPS user in PROD, because user have no password 
Also, user having the same problem with user REYR in PROD instance. This user has the ‘SELECT ANY TABLE’ privilege, so it should be able to see the tables, but doesn’t work from MS Access.
Please suggest us